# Why is my jQuery UI Autocomplete returning all items (from XML) as one long line?

Tags: jquery, xml, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using a jQuery Autocomplete but it is returning all the XML entries as one list item instead of one item/keyword

Here is my sample XML

```
<keywords>
<keyword>Hello</keyword>
<keyword>asdfasd</keyword>
<keyword>fsdgs</keyword>
<keyword>Helqerqlo</keyword>
<keyword>Hello</keyword>
<keyword>Hello</keyword>
<keyword>shjfg</keyword>
<keyword>zcxvv</keyword>
<keyword>Hello</keyword>
<keyword>fjhfhg</keyword>
<keyword>Hello</keyword>
<keyword>fdgs</keyword>
<keyword>gfhdgh</keyword>
<keyword>sdfgsdf</keyword>
<keyword>dfghd</keyword>
<keyword>xvcb</keyword>
<keyword>dfghdgh</keyword>
<keyword>Heldfghdglo</keyword>
</keywords>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $.ajax({
                url: "xml1.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function( xmlResponse ) {
                    var data = $( "keywords", xmlResponse ).map(function() {
                        return {
                            value: $( "keyword", this ).text()
                        };
                    }).get();
                    $('#ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_txtSchool').autocomplete({
                        source: data,
                        minLength: 0
                    });
                }
            });                

        });
```

And here is the only option in the autocomplete drop down list (all keywords mashed together as one long keyword)

HelloasdfasdfsdgsHelqerqloHelloHelloshjfgzcxvvHellofjhfhgHellofdgsgfhdghsdfgsdfdfghdxvcbdfghdghHeldfghdglo

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks, 
Thomas

Comment: Adding a 3 level fixed this problem... <keywords><keyword><name>example</name></keyword></keywords> - is there any way to do it without a 3rd level of xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is

```
value: $( "keyword", this ).text()
```

the text() is returning the innerText of the keyword... simples

you should just return:

```
value: $( "keyword", this )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the proper jQuery tools to handle XML, that makes it much easier :-)

```
var data = $(xmlResponse).find("keyword").map(function() {
    return { value: $(this).text() };
}).get(); // by the way, what is this 'get' for?
```

Also, looking at your code, this seems quite verbose for a "simple" AutoComplete. You may have a look at this: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete

**Update:**

I think the problem is, that you `.map()` the root element of your xml. There's only one of them, which means, you are only getting one result from the `.map()` function. In the example on the jQuery site, the xml is structured a bit different. So I'd try this (it's basically the same as above):

```
var data = $( "keyword", xmlResponse ).map(function() { // changed keywords to keyword
    return {
        value: $( this ).text() // changed $("keyword", this) to $(this)
    };
}).get();
```

I have not tested it, but I think, that should do the trick.

Comment: *1.* `.get()` turns a jQuerified object into an actual array. The call is quite necessary here. *2.* jQueryUI's autocomplete plugin is the successor to the plugin you linked to, and in fact the author recommends using the jQueryUI one.

Comment: Thanks, that was example code copied straight from http://www.jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete I just replaced with my XML info... I'm using jquery ui elsewhere on the site so I prefer to use their autocomplete rather than include more js. (again, not sure what get is for - came from autocomplete sample code)

Comment: @Andrew, thanks for the clarification about `.get()`. And of course you're right with the jQueryUI autocomplete (should have read the title...).

Comment: Ok, now it begins to dawn on me, that my answer is total non-sense. Even using `.find()` instead of `$("...", xmlResponse)` is basically the same. :-)
But I updated my answer, second try...